# connection to tabular model from sharepoint 2013 using excel 2013

Tags: connection, sharepoint-2013, ssas, excel-2013, ssas-tabular

i'm trying to create some excels with powerpivot and sharing them on sharepoint, but when i try to refresh the connection of my excels i have this error: "An error occurred during an attempt to establish a connection to the external data source.".

When i try to use the excels on my pc they work without any problem but when i share them on sharepoint i always have that error.

Unfortunately i have almost zero experience on sharepoint, i've tried to search and try some solutions but nothing worked.

Somebody has already resolved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

We faced this problem and I recall we fixed using Kerberos delegation. We needed the actual user to be passed to SSAS in order to row filter that user. It wasn't simple though. Follow this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/us-en/library/dn194199(v=sql.120).aspx

Good luck.